# How can we pass argument in single line python command

Tags: python, json, linux

I using below command for get json data:

```
cat config.json | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin); print obj['prd']['vmname']
```

Above command parse json with static value, here I want to make dynamic with pass the 'prd' and based on this print it.

I tried as below but not worked:

```
# env="prd"
# cat config.json | python ${env} -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin); print obj[sys.argv[1]]['vmname']
```

How to pass 'prd' as variable in this command?

Comment: You might consider using `jq` instead: `cat config.json | jq '.prd.vmname'` (ignoring the useless use of `cat`).

Comment: Or `jq --arg p prd '.[$p].vname]`, to parameterize the first key as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sys.argv[]` like :

```
python  -c "import sys; print(sys.argv[1])" 'test'
```

output:

```
test
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the argument after the `-c` switch:

```
cat config.json | python -c "import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin); print(obj[sys.argv[1]]['vmname'])" "prd"
```

The string `prd` will be passed as `sys.argv[1]` in the script.

Comment: The order should `-c`, then the script, then the variable. Like in the answer